# why await has differrent behaviour when used in return?

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await

I am reading the example for await here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
which has two differrent examples of using it. However it does not anywhere mention that the behaviour is differrent.

The following code:

```
function resolveAfterXSeconds(x, secs) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Resolving ",secs)
      resolve(x);
    }, secs * 1000);
  });
}

async function add(x) {
  const a = await resolveAfterXSeconds(20,4);
  const b = await resolveAfterXSeconds(30,3);
  return x + a + b;    
}

add(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);
});
```

prints:

> resolving 4
>   resolving 3
>   60

But if I modify `add` to the following:

```
async function add(x) {
  const p_a = resolveAfterXSeconds(20,4);
  const p_b = resolveAfterXSeconds(30,3);
  return x + await p_a + await p_b;
}
```

it prints the following (no matter what the order of variables is in return):

> resolving 3
>   resolving 4
>   60

Why are the numbers printed in differrent order?

Comment: You moved the await from when the function is declared via `const` to the the `return` statement so the resolution happens in a different order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version the first `resolveAfterXSeconds` function call returns a promise which is awaited, i.e. no other code in that `add` function is executed *until* the promise is resolved. Only then the next call is made to `resolveAfterXSeconds`.

In the second variant, the two `resolveAfterXSeconds` function calls are made immediately, without awaiting. So both `setTimeout` will have executed and the first one to have its callback called is the one with the lesser delay argument. So that second promise (with `secs` value 3) will resolve sooner than the first (with `secs` value 4).

The fact that you still await both promises, does not change the moment they resolve (and print to the console).

So in short, the difference is that in the first version the second promise is not created until the first one has resolved. In the second one both promises are created simultaneously. The first version will take 4+3 seconds to complete, the second version will take Max(4,3) seconds to complete.